# ASP.NET Boilerplate CORS Problem outside localhost

Tags: asp.net-core, server, cors, ip, aspnetboilerplate

I created a project using the startup templates (https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates) using ASP.NET Core 2.x, .NET Core(Cross Platform), SPA(Angular), and multiple solutions configuration. I created the database and executed necessary migrations. I am now able to use the application via localhost:4200. But, when I wanted to connect from other devices in company network using mylocalip:4200; I got CORS error.

I didn't change the template's code, but my ConfigureServices method:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // MVC
    services.AddMvc(
        options => options.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory(_defaultCorsPolicyName))
    );

    IdentityRegistrar.Register(services);
    AuthConfigurer.Configure(services, _appConfiguration);

    services.AddSignalR();

    // Configure CORS for angular2 UI
    services.AddCors(
        options => options.AddPolicy(
            _defaultCorsPolicyName,
            builder => builder
                .WithOrigins(
                    // App:CorsOrigins in appsettings.json can contain more than one address separated by comma.
                    _appConfiguration["App:CorsOrigins"]
                        .Split(",", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                        .Select(o => o.RemovePostFix("/"))
                        .ToArray()
                )
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowCredentials()
        )
    );

    // Swagger - Enable this line and the related lines in Configure method to enable swagger UI
    services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
    {
        options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "Example API", Version = "v1" });
        options.DocInclusionPredicate((docName, description) => true);

        // Define the BearerAuth scheme that's in use
        options.AddSecurityDefinition("bearerAuth", new ApiKeyScheme()
        {
            Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. Example: \"Authorization: Bearer {token}\"",
            Name = "Authorization",
            In = "header",
            Type = "apiKey"
        });
    });

    // Configure Abp and Dependency Injection
    return services.AddAbp<ExampleWebHostModule>(
        // Configure Log4Net logging
        options => options.IocManager.IocContainer.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(
            f => f.UseAbpLog4Net().WithConfig("log4net.config")
        )
    );
}
```

My Configure method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseAbp(options => { options.UseAbpRequestLocalization = false; }); // Initializes ABP framework.

    app.UseCors(_defaultCorsPolicyName); // Enable CORS!

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseAbpRequestLocalization();


    app.UseSignalR(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapHub<AbpCommonHub>("/signalr");
    });

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "defaultWithArea",
            template: "{area}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });

    // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint
    app.UseSwagger();
    // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui assets (HTML, JS, CSS etc.)
    app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
    {
        options.SwaggerEndpoint(_appConfiguration["App:ServerRootAddress"].EnsureEndsWith('/') + "swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Example API V1");
        options.IndexStream = () => Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
            .GetManifestResourceStream("Example.Web.Host.wwwroot.swagger.ui.index.html");
    }); // URL: /swagger
}
```

According to these methods the server should take the 3 URLs from appsettings.json file and allow CORS for them.

```
("CorsOrigins": "http://localhost:4200,http://localhost:8080,http://localhost:8081")
```

"http://localhost:4200" in appsettings.json is my client app url that belongs to Angular application. I tried adding mylocalip:4200 to CorsOrigins list and tried changing withOrigins(...) method in AddCors(...) with allowAnyOrigin()(it should allow any machine to connect to the server), these changes didn't work, either.

[Error seen from Chrome Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvSqH.png)

Further related question: I searched the documentation, but I couldn't find it: what are ABP's best practices when deploying the application in production mode. Is there any recommended way to do this?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: CorsOrigins isn't the Address of your resource server (that hosts the API), its from the other (client) apps that want to access it via ajax. You have to enter the public urls of the client applications in there to allow them to access your api (i.e. app1.example.com:4444, app2.company.com:5555) etc. and its not their local IPs that you enter thtere (from appsettings.json) but their public ones which they are accessible under (either domain or intranet address). Otherwise if you want allow any client to access it, use `.AnyOrigin()`

Comment: also keep in mind that http and https are different origns, since they use a different port

Comment: Thanks for your answer. "http://localhost:4200" in appsettings.json is my client app url that belongs to Angular application. I tried changing withOrigins(...) method in AddCors(...) with allowAnyOrigin(), it didn't work. Till this point, nothing is https :)

Comment: Do you receive any exceptions? Exception middleware clears the CORS headers

Comment: Nothing on the server side according to Logs.txt under App_Data folder. I added a screenshot of error as seen from Chrome browser.

Comment: Have you tried adding mylocalip:4200 to CorsOrigins setting ?

Comment: I did. I added the private ip (http://192.168.*.*:4200) that is seen on ipconfig command to CorsOrigins. Didn't work either.

Comment: Also, AllowAnyOrigin() should have already solved that problem, right?

Comment: @CanDeveci, did you solve it? Having the same issue, I think I tried everything already. But for me it doesn't work for DELETE and PUT methods, I even explicitly added them into configuration to the Startu.cs.

Comment: @Smit Nope. This was a bug. We gave up on the framework :)